# How do I programatically change a ListViewItem's Key in its collection?

Tags: winforms, listview, listviewitem

I have a Winforms ListView with several Items already in them.  As I get more information about the objects these Items represent one of the things I want to change is the Key to be used to access them from the ListViewItemCollection.  Unfortuantely, the "Add" method and constructor list a parameter "key" which isn't accessible in the public interface (or private for that matter) of ListViewItem.

How can I change the value set by "key" in the Add method?

---

<sub>I already solved it but it took me a long time, so in case someone else has the same problem, here's the answer.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Name property also changes the key in the collection.  See [ListViewItem.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.name.aspx).

Comment: +1, poor naming choices prevents one from seeing that easily.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, you're right. Seems like M$ intends to let those winforms die. Missing databinding, old fashioned naming conventions, graphic bugs ... long list of never improved things about winforms